# c# remove all white spaces from string

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql string  retreiving data for three columns and I dont want any space in betweeen these columns. I want to remove space between columns.

```
 string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
                   "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as RecordType" +
                 " , left([Claimant Name] +' ',29) " +
                " , left([Claimant Address1] +' ',29)  " +
                " , left([Claimant Address2] +' ',29) as ClaimantAddress2 " +
```

My Client requirment is like

```
**1xyz1dundas**
```

MY output is like

```
**1 xyz 1 dundas**
```

Comment: What about not adding the whitespace in the first place?

Comment: every column has a specific character length.

Comment: sQL server mangament studio

Comment: Always use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection

Comment: Your question is unclear. What if the claimant name or address contains a space in between. Should we remove that also e.g. `Street 1 Of July` should become `Street1OfJuly` or do you want just remove the ending spaces? Another point to know if your columns are of CHAR datatype or VARCHAR/NVARCHAR

Comment: Yes  i dont need spaces in between Street1OfJuly what i want and datatype is varchar.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of replace

```
stringSql .Replace("  ", string.empty);
```

in sql

```
 SELECT REPLACE(stringSql, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to remove **whitespaces** (not just **ordinary spaces** `' '`, but, say, *tabluations* `'\t'`) you can use LINQ:

```
  stringSql = new String(stringSql.Where(x => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

On SQL-Server:

```
SELECT REPLACE(yourField, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL Server :

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(a))
```

Oracle , MySQL,  SQL Server 2012   : TRIM Function

```
string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
                   "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as RecordType" +
                 " ,  RTRIM(LTRIM(left([Claimant Name] +' ',29))) " +
                " ,  RTRIM(LTRIM(left([Claimant Address1] +' ',29)))  " +
                " ,  RTRIM(LTRIM(left([Claimant Address2] +' ',29))) as ClaimantAddress2 "
```